# How can I make syntax-propertize skip part of the buffer?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax, syntax-table

In SPARQL, comments starts with a `#` and follows to the end of the line. The problem is that URI's, which is a big part of SPARQL, can also contain `#`, but then they are not the start of a comment. Like so `<http://example.com/foo#bar>`. URI's are always surrounded by `<>` and never have any spaces in them.

Normally, we would write a syntax-table like this

```
(defvar sparql-mode-syntax-table
  (modify-syntax-entry ?# "<" syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" syntax-table))
```

but this would include the `#` of a URI. Now when the buffer is font-locked, or we try to move using the defined syntax, from the part from the URI that contains a `#` is now considered a comment.

How can I make `syntax-propertize` skip marking `#` in URI's as beginning of comments?

Comment: I would like to add `syntax-propertize` as a tag, but I don't have the reputation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make `syntax-propertize` skip part of a buffer is to use `syntax-propertize-function`.

```
(defvar syntax-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((syntax-table (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">")
    syntax-table))

(defvar sparql-syntax-propertize-function
  (syntax-propertize-rules
    ("<\\S-*>" (0 "@"))
    ("#" (0 "<"))))
```

Since `syntax-propertize-rules` only propertizes a part of the buffer once and it matches from top to bottom, this will set the syntax-property for a URI (`<\\S-*>`, a string without space within `<>`) to `inherit` and therefore skip any `#` inside the URI. If it is outside it matches the second rule and is marked as a comment. The syntax table takes care of the comment ending.